# Media min and max just recognize one rule

Tags: html, css

I trying to give a min-height style depending on the resolution screen.
min-width:300px for screen > 1500px, min-with:200px > 1200px, min-width:200px > 860px etc. So I doing this:

```
@media (min-width:1500px) and (max-width:1800px)  {
  .dash .tarjet{
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}​
@media (min-width:1200px) and (max-width:1499px) {
  .dash .tarjet{
    min-height: 200px;
  }
}​
@media (min-width:860px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  .dash .tarjet{
    min-height: 150px;
  }
}​
```

but is only using the first rule.

Comment: because you can't have `max-width: 1200px and min-width: 1499px` or `max-width: 1500px and min-width: 1800px` - those are impossible. Only `max-width: 1199px and min-width: 860px` is possible.

Comment: @MichaelCoker sorry, is min-width I got confused writing this. I want to have different height for different screen sizes

Comment: do you see how you can't have `max-width: 1200px` and `min-width: 1499px`? that's mathematically impossible. the max is lower than the min. It's like saying I want a maximum of 12 apples and a minimum of 14 apples.

Comment: you're right, I fixed that but it keeps only reading the first rule, ignores the other ones

Comment: If you fixed it, post the code you're using now. It's unclear what you're trying to do. Are you trying say something like `if (viewport > 1500 && viewport < 1800) { min-height: 300 }` and `if (viewport > 1200 && viewport < 1499) { min-height: 200; }`?

Comment: I updated the post, and that's exactly what I want

Comment: Your third rule was written correctly the first time around - it should read `(min-width:860px) and (max-width: 1199px)`

Comment: well, your last rule is wrong now - it was right before. I'm assuming you changed that by mistake. But what you have works. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjPpwV however, you have a hidden, special characters in your code. Try copying and pasting the code from my codepen into your actual project

Comment: Here are the special characters, btw. http://i.imgur.com/7qEwlGe.png

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Idk why is there that character, I use sublime text all the time and is the first time that happen something like that. Thanks fot the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `min-width` for the **smallest** targeted screen size, and `max-width` for **largest**.

```
@media (min-width:1500px) and (max-width:1800px)  {
  .dash .tarjet{
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}​
@media (min-width:1200px) and (max-width:1499px) {
  .dash .tarjet{
    min-height: 200px;
  }
}​
@media (max-width:1199px) and (min-width:860px) {
  .dash .tarjet{
    min-height: 150px;
  }
}​
```

Comment: It keeps the same problem, it only get the first rule, smaller than 1500px doesn't get the others rules

Comment: Are you trying to use `min-height` or `height`?

Comment: `min-height`, but it also happen with `height`

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` must be greater than `min-width`

```
...
@media (max-width:1800px) and (min-width:1500px)  {
...
@media (max-width:1499px) and (min-width:1200px) {
...
@media (max-width:1199px) and (min-width:860px) {
...
```

Comment: It keeps the same problem, it only get the first rule, smaller than 1500px doesn't get the others rules

Comment: you could put `min-height: (n)px!important`